# How to make mouse wheel scroll setting stick (Windows XP)

Tags: mouse, scrolling

On XP, in TweakUI I set the mouse wheel to scroll by 1 line rather than the default 3. When I reboot it's always set back to 3. It's a laptop with a generic Dell mouse and I can't see any specific mouse service running in Process Explorer. It happens when docked or undocked. Any ideas how to make the setting stick?

Comment: It seems that this is a known issue with Dell (and Microsoft) mice: http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/winxp/1230847028

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my HP laptop. Try to install the latest driver from Dell.